# Как распарсить часть HTML строки?

Tags: android, html, java, парсер

Есть строка

```
<tr dir='ltr'><td class=hd><p style='*:*;'>.</td><td  class='s*'>*.*.* *:*:*<td  dir='ltr' class='s*'>DATA</tr>
```

Где * - может быть любое кол-во числовой\текстовой информации (только числа или буквы). Надо вытащить DATA

Answer (score 1):

Зачем звездочки стоят во всей строке? Можно ведь обойтись только частью с DATA.

```
  /<td\s*dir='ltr'\s*class='s.*?'>.*?<\/tr>/
```

Comment: Звездочки - потому что некоторые теги повторяются и, какя понял, надо прописывать весь неизменяемый путь. 
Спасибо за помощь, но у меня вылетает это:
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Приведите кусок кода где это происходит. Вам надо экранировать слеши и кавычки.

Comment: Делаю так :
String dateComponent = null;
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/<td\s*dir='ltr'\s*class='s.*?'>.*?<\/tr>/");
     Matcher m = p.matcher("https://site.com/");
     if (m.find()) {
      dateComponent = m.toMatchResult().group(1);
}

Ошибку видит на всей строке

Comment: @007 - что бы код выводился нормально, обрамляйте его символом \` (это где буква "Ё")

Comment: ua6xh, нет идей о решении проблемы?